# Canceling Retrofit requests or handling them when leaving the activity or fragment - android

Tags: android, retrofit

I use [Retrofit library](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) to handle JSON response from my WCF web-service.

```
RestService.getRestService().search("tools", new Callback<SearchResult>() {
    @Override
    public void success(SearchResult searchResult, Response response) {
        if( searchResult == null) return;
        textView.setText(searchResult.toString());
    } // end of success(

    @Override
    public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
            showToast(R.string.internet_sikintisi);

    }
});
```

I noticed that i get error if i leave the fragment or activity where i called this function from. Because I set text in textView where the activity or fragment is not already exists.

I modified the code to be like this:

```
RestService.getRestService().search("tools", new Callback<SearchResult>() {
    @Override
    public void success(SearchResult searchResult, Response response) {

        if( searchResult == null) return;
        try{
            textView.setText(searchResult.toString());
        } catch(Exception e) {}

    } // end of success(

    @Override
    public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
        try{
                showToast(R.string.internet_sikintisi);
            } catch(Exception e) {}
    }
});
```

Basically, the problem solved, the app is not crashing every time the user gets in and out immediately. Still there might be a better solution for this problem.

I checked and Retrofit **DOES NOT** have cancel request feature!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to added checks success and failure methods the same way you would when using an asynctask check if the context still exist or make a isActive field that you set on onResume/onPause of the activity or fragment.

Comment: How to do exactly ? by call.cancel ?

Answer (score 3):

It is **possible** to cancel Retrofit requests in Retrofit 2(beta is available now.)

```
 call.cancel();// as simple as that
```

Comment: I used Retrofit 1.9 till now, i need to push the application ASAP, in the next update i may move to Retrofit 2.0,  as it is still BETA for now. its matter of time

Comment: I have used the same code but the retrofit call is not being cancelled.